# Disable UVM warning TPRGED at time 0

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm looking for ideas of how to disable a uvm_warning that occurs in the `` `uvm_object_utils `` macro.

```
UVM_WARNING @0: reporter [TPRGED] Type name 'xxx_packet' already registered with factory. No string-based lookup support for multiple types with the same type name.
```

I don't care about string-based lookup, and I'd like to be able to use the same class name in multiple tests (I'm using per-test packages to make this work). So I'd really like to disable this warning. However, even the command line disable doesn't seem to help.

I tried:

```
+uvm_set_action=*,TPRGED,UVM_WARNING,UVM_NO_ACTION
```

This works for other warnings, but in this case the warning seems to occur even before command line arguments are processed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These messages come because of static initializations; you will not be able to turn them off.

If you don't want to register string names with the factory, use the `` `uvm_object_param_utils `` macro instead of `` `uvm_object_utils ``. The only difference is that it does not register a string with the factory. See [Parameterized Classes, Static Members and the Factory Macros](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2011/02/13/parameterized-classes-static-members-and-the-factory-macros/) for more information.

Comment: Bless you Dave. I wish I'd asked earlier. I've been annoyed and uselessly tilting at those warnings for a few months now. I've tried every way I could think of to get my call to 'set_report_id_action' to happen earlier in the sim.